# What could I substitute for coffee in an Opéra cake

Tags: substitutions, cake, coffee, french-cuisine

I would like to bake an [Opéra cake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_cake) for someone who doesn't really appreciate the taste of coffee. Since coffee and chocolate are the two main elements, I am wondering: what flavour could I substitute for coffee in my coffee buttercream? I suppose the qualities I'm looking for are a bit of bitterness, and it should go well with chocolate and orange liquor?

---

PS: I just noticed that the English wikipedia describes the sponge cake as “soaked with coffee”, but in the way I usually do it it's soaked with [Cointreau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointreau) so I don't need any replacement there.

Comment: since you are discarding the coffee flavor to accommodate your guest's dislikes, do you know what flavor that guest might enjoy?

Comment: @CosCallis she probably likes loads of things (other than coffee, I mean)… I'm really trying to keep the balance of taste in the original, just because, well, Opéra is *so* good!

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest making something else.  Substituting a major flavor ingredient seldom works out well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some sort of nutty flavor perhaps? Hazelnut syrup? I think it should go well with both chocolate and orange. Otherwise I think the cake will be quite delicious even without a substitute, just using plain buttercream.

EDIT: I just noticed that the cake has an almond base. Perhaps a few drops of Amaretto in the buttercream would work. That would play nicely with the almond flavor already there.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that *either* you want to "substitute the coffee" or "keep the original balance" because anything that does the first will not accomplish the latter.

That said, a flavor source that would work well would be **Irish Creme**.